# How to sort Bible books properly when using \bibleref and \imakeidx

Tags: sorting, imakeidx, bibleref

I expect my Bible index to sort biblical books like 1-2 Samuel, 1-2 Kings, and 1-2 Chronicles under Hebrew Bible. But they are sorted after New Testament and I need help to sort them properly.

My MWE:

````
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\RequirePackage{bibleref}
\makeindex[name=scripture,title={Bible index}]
\renewcommand{\biblerefindex}{\index[scripture]}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% bibleref
\def\hb{\textbf{Hebrew Bible}}
\def\nt{\textbf{New Testament}}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% bibleref map
\biblerefmap{Genesis}{1@\hb!01}%
\biblerefmap{IKings}{1@\hb!11}
\biblerefmap{IIKings}{1@\hb!12}
\biblerefmap{IChronicles}{1@\hb!13}
\biblerefmap{IIChronicles}{1@\hb!14}
\biblerefmap{Matthew}{3@\nt!01}
\biblerefmap{Mark}{3@\nt!02}
\biblerefmap{Luke}{3@\nt!03}
\biblerefmap{John}{3@\nt!04}


\begin{document}

This is a quote from \ibibleverse{Genesis}(2:17).
And another from the Gospel of \ibibleverse{Lk}(15:11).
Then one of \ibibleverse{IKgs}(9:3) and another from
\ibibleverse{IChr}(12:1).
The topic is the Bible.\ibibleverse{Mt}(25:3)
The beginning of \ibibleverse{Mk}(1:1).

   \printindex[scripture]

\end{document}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AshPU.jpg
````

Comment: welcome to TeX,SE!

Comment: I would l ike to add a pdf of the result of my MWE but don't know how....

Comment: The solution was to remap composite books like IKings, IIKings, etc, with the number *after* the title of the book, as follows: ```\biblerefmap{Genesis}{1@\hb!01}%
\biblerefmap{Kings1}{1@\hb!11}
\biblerefmap{Kings2}{1@\hb!12}
\biblerefmap{Chronicles1}{1@\hb!13}
\biblerefmap{Chronicles2}{1@\hb!14}```

Answer (score 1):

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[openany]{book}
\RequirePackage{bibleref}
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=scripture, title={Bible index}] 
\makeindex[name=topics, title=Index]
\renewcommand*{\biblerefindex}{\index[scripture]}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% bibleref

\def\hb{\textbf{Hebrew Bible}}
\def\dc{\textbf{Deuterocanonicals}}
\def\nt{\textbf{New Testament}}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% bibleref map
\biblerefmap{Genesis}{1@\hb!01}%
\biblerefmap{Kings1}{1@\hb!11}
\biblerefmap{Kings2}{1@\hb!12}
\biblerefmap{Chronicles1}{1@\hb!13}
\biblerefmap{Chronicles2}{1@\hb!14}
\biblerefmap{Wisdom}{2@\dc!05}%
\biblerefmap{Matthew}{3@\nt!01}
\biblerefmap{Mark}{3@\nt!02}
\biblerefmap{Luke}{3@\nt!03}
\biblerefmap{John3}{3@\nt!04}

\ibibleverse{Genesis}(2:17)\\
\ibibleverse{Luke}(15:11-32)\\
\ibibleverse{IKgs}(9:3)\\
\ibibleverse{IChr}(12:1)\\
\index[topics]{Bible}\\
\ibibleverse{Wisdom}(15:4)\\
\ibibleverse{Mt}(25:3)\\
\ibibleverse{IIIJohn}(1:5)\\
\ibibleverse{IIChr}(32:1)

   \printindex[scripture]
   \printindex[topics]

\end{document}
```